# Correct CSS for Two (Left & Mid) Column Fixed Width Left and Right Column Fluid

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-calc

I am working on a 3 column divs. The Left and Mid columns have fixed widths (57px and 160px respectively) inside the wrapper with a width of 1005px.

the problem is the right column which SHOULD be fluid width and will cover all the remaining space. I've tried using `width: (calc 100% - 217px);` but it's not working.

I have this code for your reference. I Need your help to point out what's wrong.

```css
body {
    background-color: #444;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
     width: 1005px;
     min-height:450px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn, #mid {
    float: left;
    min-height: 450px;
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn {
     width: 57px;
     background-color: #111;
}
#mid {
     width: 160px;
     background-color: #087;
}
#rightcolumn {
     max-width: calc (100% - 217px);
     background-color: #777;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        Left
    </div>
    <div id=mid>
        Mid
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8weSA/1434/

Answer (score 4):

Don't put space between `calc` and `(`, the grammar should be like this:

`width: calc(100% - 247px)`

Also note the spacing around the `-` operator, the same spacing is needed for the `+` operator but not for `/` and `*` operators.
Your `calc()` property grammar was not recognized by the browser that's why it didn't work for you.

Some useful links:

[calc() property support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

[Mathematical Expressions: calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8weSA/1435/)

Answer (score 0):

Although there are solutions given here for calc function. I wanted to show another way this could be done without using the `calc()` function. Since you made you #right div float left, it never covered the rest space. Check out below code :

```css
body {
    background-color: #444;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
     width: 1005px;
     min-height:450px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftcolumn, #mid {
    float: left;
    min-height: 450px;
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn {
     width: 57px;
     background-color: #111;
}

#mid {
     width: 160px;
     background-color: #087;
}

#rightcolumn {
    
     
     background-color: #777;
     width:auto;
     min-height: 450px;
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        Left
    </div>
    <div id=mid>
        Mid
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is your [updated fiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/8weSA/1443/)

Answer (score 0):

in `#rightcolumn`

modify the line:

`max-width: calc (100% - 217px);`

to:

`width: calc(100% - 217px);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Please remove the space between `calc` and `(100% - 217px);`

   `max-width: calc (100% - 217px);` it's wrong.

   `max-width: calc(100% - 217px);` it's Correct.
2. Use `width:100%` to `#rightcolumn` div.

visit my demo... on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/035jp180/)